# Monitor Kong API Logs Using ELK

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, kong, kong-plugin

We are using ELK (Elasticsearsh, Logstash, Kibana) version 8.x to collect logs from Kong API Gateway version 2.8 using tcp-logs plugin.

We have configured tcp-logs plugin to use Logstash as an endpoint to send the Logs to Logstash then Logstash will send the logs to Elasticsearch.

Kong TCP-Logs Plugin -> Logstash -> Elasticsearch

I do appreciate your support to clarify the following, please:

How to display Kong API Gateway Logs using Kibana? From where shall I start?
Is there Index for Kong logs will be created by default in Elasticsearch?
What is the Elasticsearch Index Pattern do I need to use to get Kong API Logs?

**Note: I am not using filebeat agent on the Kong API nodes. I am using tcp-logs plugin to send Kong logs to Logstash.**

The content of  /etc/logstash/conf.d/beats.conf

```
    input {
  beats {
    port => 5044
  }
}
filter {
  if [type] == "syslog" {
     grok {
        match => { "message" => "%{SYSLOGLINE}" }
  }
     date {
        match => [ "timestamp", "MMM  d HH:mm:ss", "MMM dd HH:mm:ss" ]
     }
  }
}
output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => ["Elstic_IP_Address:9200"]
    index => "%{[@metadata][beat]}-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
  }
}
```

Thanks so much for your support!

Comment: Could you share your current configuration on elk, especially Logstash? I believe sending logs through logstash and onto elasticsearch then creating an index pattern should be suffice.

Comment: @Ponsakorn30214 Please find the below /etc/logstash/conf.d/beats.conf


`input {
  beats {
    port => 5044
  }
}
filter {
  if [type] == "syslog" {
     grok {
        match => { "message" => "%{SYSLOGLINE}" }
  }
     date {
        match => [ "timestamp", "MMM  d HH:mm:ss", "MMM dd HH:mm:ss" ]
     }
  }
}
output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => ["ELK_IP_Address:9200"]
    index => "%{[@metadata][beat]}-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
  }
}`

Comment: Putting all the config into a comment makes it hard to read, how about editing the question and putting it there? From your config, I believe you already have an index (Should be filebeat-<version> if you're sending log from filebeat)

Comment: @Ponsakorn30214 I have updated the question with the content of  /etc/logstash/conf.d/beats.conf

Note:  I am not using filebeat agent on the Kong API nodes. I am using tcp-logs plugin to send Kong logs to Logstash.

Comment: My mistake, I misread and thought you are sending logs using beats. From your updated config, how about changing index to `index => "transaction"` and using said index to display on Kibana? Indices in elasticsearch sense are similar to what we called a database, by adding `index => transaction` we're hence telling elasticsearch to store there logs in the "transaction" database.

Comment: @Ponsakorn30214 Thanks. Now it is working fine. I will add your answer in Answer section to help other people.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix this issue, we have to use `index => "transaction"` in the content of /etc/logstash/conf.d/beats.conf configuration file.

Then using `transaction` index to display the logs on Kibana.

```
input {
  beats {
    port => 5044
  }
}
filter {
  if [type] == "syslog" {
     grok {
        match => { "message" => "%{SYSLOGLINE}" }
  }
     date {
        match => [ "timestamp", "MMM  d HH:mm:ss", "MMM dd HH:mm:ss" ]
     }
  }
}
output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => ["Elstic_IP_Address:9200"]
    index => "transaction"
  }
}
```